# Bibliography get print with lines

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using simple package \bibliographystyle{plain}. However, the bibliography get printed with lines as seen in the image.

[image: Bibliography images]

My code is below

```
\cleardoublepage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{theory/intro}
\include{theory/Pre-Processing}
\include{theory/Processing}
\include{theory/post-processing} 
\include{theory/LKW-Stone-Trapping}
\include{theory/Results_Comparision}
\include{theory/Hypothesis_Evaluation}
%\include{theory/result_discussion}
\include{theory/Conclusion_and_Outlook_2}
\include{files/Appen_2}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

I did not use any packages above.

How can I remove those lines? What steps should be taken?

Comment: If I should guess: put `\normalem` before the bib and read the documentation of the ulem package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to answer? Or close as a duplicate? Or close as unclear? Or ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show a minimal example, but I guess that you are using the `ulem` package which redefines `\emph` to underline. Use `\normalem` before the bibliographie to get back the normal `\emph` and read the documentation of `ulem`.